# Multicore ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, loess

I am trying to analyze a very large dataset (over 10 million rows; OK, it's big in my field). I'm trying to generate a smoothed regression plot using the following command:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=IV, y=DV)) + geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

This has been running for over a day now, but on a single core (leaving 7 others rather bored). Is there any way to use ggplot2 with multiple threads so as to speed things up? Local regression seems like it would be a natural for this kind of thing.

Comment: I'd do stat preprocessing outside of ggplot2 (dplyr, plyr,data.table and/or parallel equivalents), and plot only the summary.

Comment: Another option would be to subsample the data and plot only a portion of it.

Comment: I would love this feature as well.  Some of my plots take 5 minutes or more to draw, and CPU usage only goes up to 25%...